# Multiple Declaration error ignored in classes, why?

Tags: c++, class, variables, inheritance, global-variables

Consider the following code fragment:

```
int test;                //global variable
class Base
{
     int test;           //private member of Base
   public:
     void getit()
     {
          cin>>test;
     }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
   public:
     void check()
     {
          test++;        //neither access global test nor the member of Base
     }
};
```

In the above code, observe the variable `test`. It is first declared globally and then again declared inside the class in private scope.

My question first question is **how the compiler is allowing multiple declaration for the variable `test` and why not giving an error?**

Also, when the function `check()` tries to access `test`, compiler gives an error. I know the private members are not inherited and are not accessible outside class, but their exists a global variable, which must be accessible.

Second question is **which `test` is present inside `check()` whether the global one or one which it is declared inside class `Base`? Also, how to access that global `test`?**

Comment: The global is called `text`, not `test`, and in any case it can be accessed as `::text` (or `::test`, if that's what it's meant to be), if it's shadowed by an instance variable.

Comment: dat was a typing mistake...srry!

Comment: OK - read up on the scope resolution operator: `::`.

Comment: i know about :: scope resolution operators, these also don't work in these cases.

Comment: though it works if i use `Base::test`, but still the global one is not accessible.

Comment: You evidently don't know *enough* about the scope resolution operator - change `test++` to `::test++` and the code will work.

Comment: ok dat is okay, but why i m not getting an error for multiple declarations?

Comment: It's quite common and normal for an instance variable to *shadow* a global. See http://ideone.com/fS71Nd for a working example.

Comment: please explain this shadowing of variables briefly. Thank you.

Comment: It's already explained in the answer from @LightnessRacesInOrbit below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How the compiler is allowing multiple declaration for the variable test and why not giving an error?

This is a basic tenet of C++'s scope rules. Conceptually, it's no different than declaring a local variable with the same name as a global variable.

**The `test` in the global namespace does not conflict with the `test` member variable** (though one does "hide" the other when used in an unqualified way, because the member will take priority during lookup).

This is simply how the language is designed, and it's a good thing.

---

> Also, when the function check() tries to access test, compiler gives an error.

The important thing to consider is precisely *what* that error is. It's not telling you that no symbol `test` can be found; it's telling you that it's found the member variable, and that you have no access to it.

That tells you that access specifiers do not affect *visibility*, only *accessibility*:
 **your member `test` still hides the global `test`, even though you can't access it**.

To specify the global `test`, you'd need to write `::test`.

Answer (score 2):

The global variable is hidden by the local `test` variable. Hence you do not get a compiler error. You can see more details [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/).

To access the global variable within the class, you have to use,

```
::test
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 1;

int main()
{
   std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

   int x = 2;

   std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
   std::cout << "x = " << ::x << std::endl;

   {
      int x = 3;

      std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

      std::cout << "x = " << ::x << std::endl;
  }

   std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
   std::cout << "x = " << ::x << std::endl;
}
```

Any name declared in internal declarative region hides the same name declared in the enclosing declarative region.

As for your example then member functions start to seek names in the scope of the class where they are declared.

So member function getit

```
 void getit()
 {
      cin>>test;
 }
```

starts to seek name test in the scope of the class and indeed such name is declared in the class.

As for function check then access method does not influense on the search of the name. The finction finds the name in the scope of its base class. As this name is not accessible the compiler issues an error.